# Problem with arraylist, what does the if statement do?

Tags: java

Can someone please explain this code to me.
Here i is set to 1 which is then refered to later in the code

```
        int i = 1;       
        List data = new ArrayList<>();
        String column1 = new String();
        String column2 = new String();
        String column3 = new String();
        String column4 = new String();
        String column5 = new String();
        String column6 = new String();
        String column7 = new String();
        String column8 = new String();
        String column9 = new String();
        String column10 = new String();
        String column11 = new String();
        String column12 = new String();
```

And in this if statement, if i is equal to 1, it then does i++.
Does this keep going until all rows are cover or Im I missing something?
When does it go to the else statement?
Rad is row in Swedish btw.

```
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("winequality-white.csv"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            String rad;
            while ((rad = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    String[] radArray = rad.split(";");
                    column1 += radArray[0] += ",";
                    column2 += radArray[1] += ",";
                    column3 += radArray[2] += ",";
                    column4 += radArray[3] += ",";
                    column5 += radArray[4] += ",";
                    column6 += radArray[5] += ",";
                    column7 += radArray[6] += ",";
                    column8 += radArray[7] += ",";
                    column9 += radArray[8] += ",";
                    column10 += radArray[9] += ",";
                    column11 += radArray[10] += ",";
                    column12 += radArray[11] += ",";

                    //System.out.println(data.toString());
                }

            }
            data.add(column1 += ";");
            data.add(column2 += ";");
            data.add(column3 += ";");
            data.add(column4 += ";");
            data.add(column5 += ";");
            data.add(column6 += ";");
            data.add(column7 += ";");
            data.add(column8 += ";");
            data.add(column9 += ";");
            data.add(column10 += ";");
            data.add(column11 += ";");
            data.add(column12 += ";");

            reader.close();
            return data;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It's just skipping the first line of the file.

Comment: Without seeing the input, it would appear to be a way of skipping the first line of input.

Comment: the i++ instruction will be fired only one time in the loop and after that the else statement will be extecuted until loop is finished

Comment: Now, if I had to write that code, I would put `int i = 1` just before the loop, to make its use a lot more clear. Unless it's used again down the road (which it doesn't appear to be) it makes no sense putting it so far from the loop that uses it.

Comment: Also, `new String()` is almost never something you want to write. (Literally never, if you're still just starting out with Java.) In the above, `""` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` skips processing the first line of the file, probably because it contains headers. `i` starts out being `1`, so on the first loop iteration, `if (i == 1)` is true and it does `i++;` which sets `i` to `2`. So on the next loop iteration (and all others), `i == 1` is false and the `else` branch is taken, processing the line.

Comment: Wow. After being stuck with this so long, you make it sound so simple. Thank you!